# SoundCloud: /resolve

Tags: soundcloud

How do you implement SoundCloud's [resolve](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve) resource?

I want to lookup a track's id given another property like track permalink.

Hoping someone can provide some example code for me to dissect and learn.

Answer (score 2):

it's pretty simple.

1. register an app on soundcloud to get your client key (your_client_id in next line)
2. here is an example `http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID`
3. and here is the documentation: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve

you will receive xml or json object back, with all the properties you need

Comment: how would you read the json back into the page to display the correct profile?